# WebApi Action filter called twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

My WebApi filter method `OnActionExecuted` is being called twice.
My filter (I make it as simple as possible):

```
   public class NHibernateActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
   { 
        //  [Inject]
        //   public ISessionFactoryProvider sessionFactoryProvider { get; set; }
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
           var a = 5;
           var b = a;
           //new BaseSessionProvider(sessionFactoryProvider).EndContextSession();
        }
    }
```

My setup:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521040/how-to-add-global-asp-net-web-api-filters
        FilterConfig.RegisterWebApiFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
    }

    public class FilterConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterWebApiFilters(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection filters)
        {
             filters.Add(new NHibernateActionFilter());
        }
     }
```

In debugger I catch `OnActionExecuted` twice with the same `actionExecutedContext`. Why?

**UPD**

```
Controller
public class BankSmsController : ApiController
{
         [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
         public int GetTest()
         {
             return 1;
         }
}
```

Comment: I noticed an `Inject` attribute commented out - could there be some NInject config that sets up filters as well so it's being added twice? Have you confirmed that there is only one instance of the filter in the global filters collection after all the startup code has finished running?

Comment: No ninject at all. I remove `kernel.BindFilter<NHibernateActionFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 1);`

Comment: can you show the controller?

Comment: May be you have `[NHibernateActionFilter]` directly on your controller and in global filter. Therefore it is executed twice.

Comment: I attach my controller. no attributes on it or action

Answer (score 8):

I have a suspicion, that this strange behavior can be fixed by either overriding `AllowMultiple` property of filter and returning false, or applying `AttributeUsage` attribute with `AllowMultiple` set to false too (this influences on default implementation of `AllowMultiple` property of filter.

At least in our project this helped (we have filters injected via Autofac).

Comment: Using `AllowMultiple` is more like a hack, something is registering the action filter twice.

Comment: @DanielLittle what could be the potential culprit?

Comment: Personally I had the attribute defined once in my `WebApiConfig` file and once on my base controller class.

Answer (score 3):

This might be caused due to a registration of a custom filter provider. When you do this, you need to unregister the default one. Otherwise, if you are getting the usual filters in your custom one, they will be registered twice and consequently, executed twice.

Code should be something like this:

```
// remove default action filter provider
var defaultFilterProvider = config.Services.GetFilterProviders().Single(provider => provider is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);
config.Services.Remove(typeof(IFilterProvider), defaultFilterProvider);

// add custom filter provider
config.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new CustomFilterProvider(container));
```

As have been said, AllowMultiple to false is a hack since .net is clever enough to only execute once a filter even if it has been registered several times. Also, there are scenarios where you do need this to be true.

Comment: Thanks for this code but i coundn't able to find FilterProvider with ActionDesctiptorFilterProvider type it give me error Sequence contains no matching element

Comment: Depends on the actual application configuration, but all matching filters should be removed/replaced: `config.Services.RemoveAll(typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), provider => provider is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);`

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had specified the filter twice. In my IOC config file I had

```
builder.Register(c => new SelectListFilter(c.Resolve<ClientManager>()))
        .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>()
        .InstancePerRequest();
        .RegisterFilterProvider();
```

And then in filterConfig I had

```
filters.Add(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IActionFilter>());
```

I removed the line from filterConfig and everything was better.