# OnActionExecuted being called twice in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute, onactionexecuted

I am trying to do some stuff after my controller is done with the action at OnActionExecuted.
However the method is called twice.

My filter method

```
public class TestFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {

       //do stuff here


    }
}
```

and my controller

```
[TestFilter]
  public class BaseController : ApiController
{
 public LoginResponseDTO Login(LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO)
    {

 //do login stuff
    }

}
```

when i try this filter, the onActionExecuted Method gets called twice which causes my action in the method to be applied twice to the response. I have searched for a reason but cannot find a solution.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant stack trace that shows both TestFilters being fired in one callstack?

Comment: I can see the same thing happening in my code. A breakpoint in the controller and the onactionexectued shows that the controller is fired first, then OnActionExectued is fired twice.

Comment: I had the same issue

        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

fixed it for me.

Comment: @Martijn that worked perfectly... Wish you had said that as an answer so I could up vote it...

Answer (score 27):

The answer is from @Martijn comments above:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
 public class TestFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
```

All credits goes to him. 
(Note: I'll remove the post, if he decide to add the comment as answer)

Comment: In my case I need to add only [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)] as rest everything derived from ActionFilterAttribute class.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was I was calling /myApi/action which was redirecting to /myApi/action/ and this caused OnActionExecuted() to run twice.

I filtered out where *filterContext.Result is RedirectResult* within OnActionExecuted since I wasn't interested in running my code then. The HTTP status code showed as 200 on both the calls so filtering by that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the AllowMultiple inside your ActionFilterAttribute, like so:

```
public override bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  //Your logic
}
```

That will stop your ActionFilter being called twice. Also check that it is not registered twice. Check out this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485479/webapi-action-filter-called-twice/33145725) to see more about that.

Do be aware that AttributeUsage attribute is a single-use attribute--it can't be applied more than once to the same class, as you will find in the remarks section of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage).

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered the custom filter in Global.asax.cs, like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new TestFilterAttribute());
```

Please revoke the attribute above your custom controller.

Comment: This was my issue, except in the WebApiConfig.cs file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [BasicAuthenticateFilter] is not in "Controller" level as well as "Method" level. It will run twice.