# Webapi Inbound and outbound actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using WebApi for a rest service. I need to have every request hit a inbound filter/action (to price the request) and hit a outbound filter/action (to bill the results). About a month ago I came across the term but I can't see to recall it.  Something like "PostAction" or "PostFilter".  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: you might be referring to `RegisterGlobalFilters` ?

Comment: Searching on that, let's see.

Comment: Still looking at RegisterGlobalFilters, but I need to execute code before the controller executes, and after the controller executes.  I haven't see how RegisterGlobalFilters can be ran before and after controller.  Still looking though.

Comment: Take a look here, this may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: That's looking good.  I'm trying some prototype code to test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at this link [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), they have an example of how to apply a custom filter `attribute` to a controller, which is applied to all `Action` methods.

Here's an example of the code from the link...

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can see the custom filter added to the controller.

In your scenario, the [IActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) may be of use, which has two `OnActionExecuted` & `OnActionExecuting`.

Take a look at [How to add global ASP.Net Web Api Filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521040/how-to-add-global-asp-net-web-api-filters) for help with WebAPI.

Comment: I don't think it will work. For a controller to work in WebApi, I have to derive from ApiController.  When I derive from Controller, WebApi is breaking.  When I switch it back to ApiController, WebApi starts working.  At least based upon my prototype.

Comment: ok, let me give this a try.  I think I understand the plumbing.

Comment: Ok got it working. `ActionFilterAttribute` was what I used to derive from and implemented `OnActionExecuted` and `OnActionExecuting`.  Reference `System.Web.Http.Filters` and NOT `System.Web.Mvc`