# WebAPI ActionFilterAttribute OnExecuting not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Web API `ActionFilterAttribute`

```
namespace namespace.Filters {

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
    using System.Web.Http.Filters;

    public class LogApiRequestActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

        public LogApiRequestActionFilterAttribute() {
        }

        private void logData(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            var controllerName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.FullName;
            var actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var parameters = "";

            foreach (var item in actionContext.ActionArguments) {
                parameters += string.Format("{0} = {1}, ", item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            if (parameters.Any()) {
                parameters = parameters.Remove(parameters.Count() - 2);
            }

            var message = string.Format("{0}.{1}({2})", controllerName, actionName, parameters);
            // Do the logging
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            logData(actionContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

When I add it globally over the `WebApiConfig.cs` like this:

```
config.Filters.Add(new LogApiRequestActionFilterAttribute());
```

But the `logData` method never gets called. Does anyone know why?

Comment: should the type of the `actionContext` parameter be a `ActionExecutingContext` instead?

Comment: @DLeh, this is how Visual Studio implemented the interface for me :)

Comment: sorry for a very basic question, but how do you know that its not reaching there??

Comment: @entre, it doesn't log anything and it doesn't step into it :)

Comment: this might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9521363/1236044

Comment: problem might be mvc filters v/s webapi filters,

Comment: @entre in which place exactly?

Comment: @jbl that doesn't help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found my problem, thanks a lot to **now he who must not be named**.

My filter was properly registered and also perfectly loaded, just the method I was testing AND debugging with, wasn't called with a request. It was called from an razor helper and there the `Request`-property is `null` of course.

So the fix is to use an action which is called with an `http request` and not just as normal method call.

Answer (score 4):

Did you decorate your controller (or any action method), with that filter ?

For e.g.

1. After creating a filter called LogApiRequestActionFilterAttribute, you need to register it (as you have done).
2. After registration, if the filter has to be applied at the **controller level**, then **decorate your controller** with that filter.
3. If the filter has to be applied only on **certain action method**, **put the filter on that particular action method(s)**

   ```
   [LogApiRequestActionFilter]
    public class YourController : ApiController
    { //--->controller level filter
       [LogApiRequestActionFilter] //-->action level filter
       public IHttpActionResult DoAction()
       {

       }

    }
   ```
4. If neither of them works out, when the action method executes, put a **breakpoint and analyse the `http request`. Check If your filter is registered or not**

Comment: I know, what my mistake was. And you helped. The problem was, that the Controller I was testing with wasn't called with a request. I just called the method directly in it...

Comment: Decorating the controller with the attribute did the trick for me. Thanks a lot