# MVC4 - Custom Controller for all calls (including WebAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am building an MVC4 application, where I have the normal MVC views and I have added a few WebAPI controllers.
I know that the corresponding controllers exist in different namespaces (System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Http).

So, I want to create a custom controller which will capture all incoming calls (to webpages and to WebAPI), register the call and perform authorisation, all in one class for consistency.

Is there a MVC way to do that?
If this cannot be done with 1 custom controller, is there any other approach to this? Would a HttpModule be a good idea for an MVC application?

Right now, I have created 2 similar classes which derive from:
System.Web.Http.ApiController and
System.Web.Mvc.Controller
but does not seem like a good idea, as I almost duplicate the code.

Comment: have you looked at the [Authorize] attribute? You can implement your own by inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement such functionality is to create a custom HttpModule and register it with Http Pipeline.

You can find the reference to Custom HttpModule and Registration process [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx)

Comment: @spiros - Thanks for accepting my Answer. I did not follow what you meant by more complex.

Comment: Where in the pipeline should I register my HttpModule?

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this pourpose is better to use global filters.
But you will need slightly different implementations for Mvc and WebApi

See some examples here:
[How to add global ASP.Net Web Api Filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521040/how-to-add-global-asp-net-web-api-filters)

Comment: if i understood correctly, i will still have to implement 2 filters, 1 for mvc and 1 for webapi, right?

Comment: Yes, they'll be very similar but yes.