# How to inspect the response before formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there any 'catch all' point in Asp.NET Core pipeline (MVC) that would enable us inspecting and modifying the response before serialization (formatting) kicks in?

In some cases, we would like to mask data returned from services and ideally implemented this in a generic way for all controllers, rather than having to write the same code controller by controller.

I cannot see any extension point where we could inspect and modify the response (ActionResult) from the controllers before the response is serialized (formatted) using the desired formatting.

Comment: Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#result-filters). Essentially, you want an ActionFilter

Comment: have you considered to use global Filters? [Here is and exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521040/how-to-add-global-asp-net-web-api-filters)

Comment: Thank you, completely forgot about those, does the job